# Can't sort by time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble sorting my database by time. I can get the date to work but my other attributes don't.

Time is defined as `t.time :start_time` in my migration. The other attributes I've been checking it against is `t.decimal :cost` and `t.date :date`.

In my controller:

```
@event = Event.all.order(:start_time) #should sort by start_time, but doesn't work
@event = Event.all.order(:cost) #should sort by cost, but doesn't
@event = Event.all.order(:date) #sorts the date by ascending order
```

My other attributes are returning correct values. An instance of each returns `2000-01-01 14:00:00 UTC` and `40.0`.

Is there something I'm missing about .order()?

**Edit:** It looks like the date portion of the time return `2000-01-01 14:00:00` is getting in the way. It's sorting correctly, but my  actual `:date` and `:time` date aren't synced. Anyone have a solution to pass the value of `:date` to the `:time` date when a user submits the form? Maybe through a hidden field?

Comment: do you have a default scope somewhere? try `Event.unscoped.order(:start_time)`

Comment: No default scopes anywhere. When I used the unscoped method it bypassed some other scopes I had, but it still didn't return the items in the correct order.

Comment: You call leave the `all` and call as `Event.order(:start_time)`

Comment: Although :cost sorts correctly with the unscoped method. Hmm.

Comment: with `all` off it's sorting it differently from before. I'm thinking maybe the problem with the date/year information that's before the time. Is there a way to bypass that and get right to the hour? Or better yet, remove it from the database? I'm not sure why it gets stored when I specified `time`

Comment: So the time is actually being sorted correctly without `all` there, but the date it stores is 2000-01-01, which is different from the separate date I'm storing. I'll look for a way to pass the date I'm storing to the `:start_time` and `:end_time` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `all` on the method returned the correct results.

```
@event = Event.order(:cost)
```